# Make Chrome stop saving password on a website

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

I had configured Chrome to save password on one particular website.

But now I don't want Chrome to save it. Naturally, I went to saved passwords from wrench menu and deleted the saved password.

The problem is, whenever I login to that website again, Chrome saves my password again. It's like Chrome thinks that it's supposed to save that password and even if I delete it, it will save it again.

How do I stop this behavior? Is there any way to manually add a website to "Never Saved" list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you remove the website form the list at `Settings - Advanced settings - Password and forms - Managed saved passwords`and then try to log in again, Chrome should prompt you to save password again. Here you should chose **Never for this site** in the dropdown. This sould work, I just tested it.

Besides this, I have not found any way to manually add a website to "Never saved".

Read more about this subject in the [Google Chrome Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95606?p=settings_password&rd=1).

Comment: Unfortunately, the "Never" never works. Next time you are on the page the offer to save password is there again.  And will do that time and time again and you need to press the "Never" button every single time!

Comment: I agree with @Bogdan, as of Chrome 102, this still does not work properly.

Comment: This solution from 2014 seems to no longer work. Removing the site from Chrome's password keeper still automatically saves the password for me with no prompt to save or never save it. Any new solution?

Comment: Worked for me on Chrome 120.0.6099.130 (01feb2024).

Answer (score -1):

If the popup for Never save password for the doesn't show up, there will be a key logo in the right side of the address bar you can click and it will give you the option to never save the password for that site...

Comment: Sadly, this seems to no longer be true. Any new solution for today?